# selenium pandas dataframe constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

The purpose of this code is to scrape a web page and extract data from a table then convert it to pandas data frame.

The scraping and data extracting went well.

The output is like this:

Release Date

Time

Actual

Forecast

Previous

Sep 09, 2018 (Aug)

21:30

0.7%

0.5%

0.3%

Aug 08, 2018 (Jul)

21:30

0.3%

0.2%

-0.1%

Jul 09, 2018 (Jun)

21:30

-0.1%

0.1%

-0.2%

Jun 08, 2018 (May)

21:30

-0.2%

-0.1%

-0.2%

May 09, 2018 (Apr)

21:30

-0.2%

-0.1%

-1.1%

Apr 10, 2018 (Mar)

21:30

-1.1%

-0.5%

1.2%

Mar 08, 2018 (Feb)

21:30

1.2%

0.8%

0.6%

Feb 08, 2018 (Jan)

21:30

0.6%

0.7%

0.3%

But when I tried to convert it to data frame I got an error.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/chinese-cpi-743'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

while True:
    try:
        item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@id,"showMoreHistory")]/a')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
    except Exception:break

for table in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
    for data in data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data.strip(), columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
        print(df)
```

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/ff.py", line 22, in 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.strip(), columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])

File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 422, in **init**
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make changes to the last part

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
pos =  0
for table in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td]")]
    if data:
        df.loc[pos] = data[0:5]
        pos+=1
print(df)
```